# Pytest fixtures with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scope, pytest, fixtures

I have created pytest fixture for initalization of webdriver:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request, cmdopt):
    browser = cmdopt
    if browser == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.get(Configuration.TEST_PAGE)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

Scope of this function is class and I can use that in every created class which is good for e2e tests.

But what if I want to test a login for multiple inputs (invalid login, password etc.) - then I need to close the driver after every test and I need function scope then. Is this a proper approach? Maybe I should create another fixture with scope of function or create a dynamic fixture scope?

My example tests - (In TestLoginSmoke I want to have fixture(scope="class")) and in TestLogin I want to have fixture(scope="function")

```
@pytest.mark.smoke
class TestLoginSmoke(BaseTest):

    def test_page_title(self, login_page_obj):
        login_page = login_page_obj
        assert login_page.get_page_title(Configuration.PAGE_TITLE) == Configuration.PAGE_TITLE

    def test_login_valid(self, login_page_obj):
        login_page = login_page_obj
        login_page.insert_username(Configuration.VALID_USERNAME_1)
        login_page.insert_password(Configuration.VALID_PASSWORD)
        login_page.start_login()


class TestLogin(BaseTest):

    def test_login_valid_multiple_input(self, login_page_obj):
        pass
```